Finding the rook polynomial for the white squares of the standard 8 × 8 chessboard.

Rook polynomial
The hint given is to have 2 4x4 white squares that are along a diagonal. They are disjoint since they don't share any rows or columns. This is the recommended way to solve them, I am just completely lost and not sure how to go about this problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Take a look at this way of decomposing the whites into two sets (colored red and green here).

Those two sets have no affect on each other, you can place the rooks on them independently. Hence the rook polynomial will be the product of the rook polynomials of these subboards (each of which is a full $4\times 4$ board). To make it more evident, you can re-index the board as A,C,E,G,B,D,F,H and 1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8. Then it will look like a two $4$ by $4$ blocks on the diagonal as mentioned in the hint.

Okay this makes sense, thanks so much! So going by what you said can we find the rook polynomial of a regular 4x4 and square it to get the final answer since they are disjoint?

Yes, you got it!
